# Opening a PDF file from within a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer

I have a WPF application in which the GUI displays a few different aspects of the application to the user, using a different `tab` for each part of the application. I am now looking to add the functionality to load and view document from within the application on one of the tabs.

I have added a `DocumentViewer` to the tab, and can see that it is displayed in the GUI when I run my application, but I'm not sure how to get that `DocumentViewer` to load/ display a document, and can't seem to find any method calls/ markup that enable you to do this.

The XAML markup I am using to add the `DocumentViewer` to my application is:

```
<TabItem Header="Document Viewer">
    <StackPanel>
        <DocumentViewer x:Name="docViewer" Height="643" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0"/>
            <DocumentViewer x:Name="documentViewer" Height="1" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <DocumentViewer.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </DocumentViewer.RenderTransform>
            </DocumentViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

How do I point this `DocumentViewer` to a PDF (or .doc, or whatever) file that's located on my computer, so that it will load and display that document inside my application window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render PDF using DocumentViewer control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430177/render-pdf-using-documentviewer-control)

Comment: Sorry, not possible - `DocumentViewer` is for `FixedDocuments` like XPS, not PDF. XPS can be loaded like this: `XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.Read);
documentViewer.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();`

Comment: pls also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430177/render-pdf-using-documentviewer-control

Comment: "point this DocumentViewer to a PDF (or .doc, or whatever) file" this is too generic to provide a proper answer. Please make the question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240314/embed-a-pdf-into-a-wpf-application) . Wpf does no provide a base class for that and if you want to work around it you couod open the pdf in its own application using 
               System. Diagnostics.Process.Start (@"filename.pdf");

You could also visit the link for other options.

Answer (score 1):

GemBox libraries can convert files to `XpsDocument` object which you could assign to `DocumentViewer` control.

For example, here is how to do that [for PDF](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/pdf-xpsdocument-wpf/1001) with GemBox.Pdf:

```
XpsDocument xpsDocument;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    using (var document = PdfDocument.Load("input.pdf"))
    {
        this.xpsDocument = document.ConvertToXpsDocument(SaveOptions.Xps);
        this.docViewer.Document = this.xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
}
```

And [for DOC](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/word-xpsdocument-wpf/5201) with GemBox.Document:

```
XpsDocument xpsDocument;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var document = DocumentModel.Load(path);
    this.xpsDocument = document.ConvertToXpsDocument(SaveOptions.XpsDefault);
    this.docViewer.Document = this.xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
}
```

Note, in both cases the `XpsDocument` object must stay referenced so that `DocumentViewer` can access its resources. Otherwise, GC will collect/dispose `XpsDocument` and `DocumentViewer` will no longer work.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using a free PDF Lib for c#.

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html#.V0RVLfmLRpg is a good example!

To view PDFs in WPF converting single pages to image and show that is a good solution.